# value="" on an input element with type="color" not working

Tags: html

For some reason, `value=""` on an color type input won't work. Whenever I go into inspect element, it gives me this error: `The specified value "ff0000" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "#rrggbb" where rr, gg, bb are two-digit hexadecimal numbers.` I don't know how to fix this, or why it is happening. Its probably something stupid I'm missing, so here is my code:

```html
<input type="color" id="colorpick" class="colorpick" name="colorpick" value="ff0000">
```

This should turn it red when ran, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/color):

> The value of an `<input>` element of type color is always a `DOMString` which contains a 7-character string specifying an RGB color in hexadecimal format. While you can input the color in either upper- or lower-case, it will be stored in lower-case form. The value is never in any other form, and is never empty.

`<input>` wants a seven-character RGB hex color. That means leading with a `#`.

```
<input type="color" id="colorpick" class="colorpick" name="colorpick" value="#ff0000">
```

Note the `#` in front of `ff0000`.

Comment: Thank you!!! I knew it was something like that that I was missing!